# Como soluciono este error de metodo de login en node js?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, postgresql, ejs

Estoy haciendo un login con node js pero al tratar de hacer el logueo no entra cuando el inicio de sesion es exitoso la linea de error es la siguiente " if (results && results.length > 0 && (await bcrypt.compare(pass, results[0].pass))) {"

Este es mi metodo para logueo
`

```
exports.login = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const user = req.body.user;
      const pass = req.body.pass;
  
      if (!user || !pass) {
        // Mostrar SweetAlert si alguno de los campos está vacío
        return res.render('login', {
          alert: true,
          alertTitle: 'Error',
          alertMessage: 'Por favor, completa todos los campos',
          alertIcon: 'error',
          showConfirmButton: true,
          timer: null,
          ruta: 'login'
        });
      }
  
      db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $1', [user], async (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          // Mostrar SweetAlert de error en la misma vista
          return res.render('login', {
            alert: true,
            alertTitle: 'Error',
            alertMessage: 'Error al consultar la base de datos',
            alertIcon: 'error',
            showConfirmButton: true,
            timer: null,
            ruta: ''
          });
        }
  `your text`
        if (results && results.length > 0 && (await bcrypt.compare(pass, results[0].pass))) {
          // Mostrar SweetAlert de éxito en la misma vista
          return res.render('login', {
            alert: true,
            alertTitle: 'Éxito',
            alertMessage: 'Inicio de sesión exitoso',
            alertIcon: 'success',
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 2000,
            ruta: ''
          });
        } else {
          // Mostrar SweetAlert de error en la misma vista
          return res.render('login', {
            alert: true,
            alertTitle: 'Error',
            alertMessage: 'Credenciales inválidas',
            alertIcon: 'error',
            showConfirmButton: true,
            timer: null,
            ruta: ''
          });
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  `
```

La unica alerta que esta haciendo es la del primer if , si los campos estan vacios. De ahi en fuera los demas no entra con ninguno y rechaza la conexion.

Comment: No entiendo porque tienes `results[0].pass`, puedes probar a hacer un `console.log` de results para ver que es. Por otro lado, en lugar de tener `const user` y `const pass` puedes hacer `const { user, pass } = req.body`

Comment: Luego parece que tienes los `if-else` dentro de la query.